# Header Location relative path compatibility

Tags: php, html, redirect, header

Is this **relative location** html header absolutely compatible with all browsers at all platforms? Any standards ?

```
Location: some_script.php?la=2&po=2030
```

I mean, will it always redirect to some_script.php at the current dir or not?

Comment: as it's PHP, the browser won't even know about the header, it just notices it is being redirected, because PHP is executed on the server.

Comment: @11684: The client's browser will absolutely receive a Location header. How else do you think it decides to change its location?

Comment: @11684 Your wrong. PHP is executed on the server, yes. But PHP send the header to the browser (client) and the client do whatever he want with it.

Comment: @DavidBélanger Doesn't PHP tell the webserver to send the header? O.o

Comment: @DavidBélanger I did not know that, thanks for learning me something!

Comment: @AlexLunix doesn't Apache interpret the PHP?

Comment: @11684 PHP interprets the PHP, then forwards the result to apache to serve. (Correct me if I'm wrong)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The standard would be this:

```
header('Location: http://www.mywebsite.com/yourpage.php?id=32', TRUE, 302);
```

But to answer your question, yes it will redirect to the page X in the current folder if you don't put a slash at first or a complete URL.

Here's an idea I would suggest you do for every website you do. In your primary file (the main php file you use like config or whatever), create something like that :

```
define('URL', 'http://www.mywebsite.com/');
```

So when you create a redirection, a link or whatever, you do this :

```
header('Location: '.URL.'yourpage.php?id=32', TRUE, 302);
```

EDIT: November 2017. As pointed by @jordanbtucker below, the HTTP spec has been updated in June 2014 (this post is from 2012) to allow relative URIs in the Location header.

Comment: yes, I am already use **relative** variant and its work for me, but I doubt that it does not work for all users. I can make add part of url to get absolute path, but its will give some troubles for debbugging this sctipt at local machine, because on the we some_script.php always at http://domain.com/some_script.php and its not the problem to add SERVER_HOST to url, but on the local machine script at subfolder...

Comment: Ok. Then I suggest tou take a look at http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-10.3.3 . The good way, the best way and the way it is suppose to work is you need to supply the full URL.

Comment: @abrahab I don't know understand why it's a problem to have the complete URL on a local machine sub-folder ?

Comment: The HTTP spec has been updated to allow relative URI's for the value of the Location header. http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-7.1.2

Answer (score -1):

The best way is

```
$server = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
$port = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PORT']) && !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PORT']) ? ':'. $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PORT'] : '';
$protocol = $_SERVER['PROTOCOL'] = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) && !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) ? "https://" : "http://";
$destination = 'some_script.php?la=2&po=2030';
$url = $protocol . $server . $port . $destination;
header('Location: '. $url, TRUE);
```

Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent.

Comment: The question is a simple yes/no and has already been answered. No request was made for code, and dumping a bunch of code without explanation is rarely useful anyway.

Comment: The request was:
Header Location relative path compatibility, marked as duplicate on a different question (Is a 302 redirect to relative URL valid, or invalid?).
I had to independently solve my problem of reaching the internal pages of the site with different headers.
This is the solution that allows you to reach the various pages regardless of the compatibility of the base addresses.