# PHP If Statements Not Firing

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm currently building a system for a football league. And are currently working on the script file for adding results. Most of the script works and the result is always successfully added to the database. However the authentication part seems to fail. The if statement on line 12 does not seem to fire and I can't understand why.

My code can be found in the pastebin link here: http://pastebin.com/ty4pdGgn

```
<?PHP

include 'functions.php';
dbConnect();

//$userEmail = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["userEmailText"]);
$userCode = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["userPasscodeText"]);

$authenticated = false;

$userEmail = "info@example.com";
if ($userEmail == "info@example.com") {
        header('Location: ../results.php?error=authentication');
}

$allUsers = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE email = '$userEmail'");
while ($thisUser = mysql_fetch_assoc($allUsers)){
        if ($userCode != $thisUser['passCode']) {
                header('Location: ../results.php?error=authentication2');
        }
        echo $thisUser['passCode'];
        $authenticated = true;
        $userID = $thisUser['userID'];
}

if (!$authenticated) {
        header('Location: ../results.php?error=authentication3');
}

$dateSubmitted = $_POST['submissionDate'];
$homeTeam = $_POST['homeTeam'];
$awayTeam = $_POST['awayTeam'];
$homeGoals = $_POST['homeGoals'];
$awayGoals = $_POST['awayGoals'];

if ($homeTeam == $awayTeam) {
        header("Location: ../results.php?error=team");
}

if (getTeamLeague($homeTeam) != getTeamLeague($awayTeam)) {
        header("Location: ../results.php?error=league");
} else {
        $leagueID = getTeamLeague($homeTeam);
}

if ($homeGoals > $awayGoals) {
        $winnerID = $homeTeam;
} else if ($homeGoals < $awayGoals) {
        $winnerID = $awayTeam;
} else if ($homeGoals == $awayGoals) {
        $winnerID = -1;
}

$cQuery = mysql_query("INSERT INTO results VALUES ('', $userID, '$dateSubmitted', $leagueID, $homeTeam, $homeGoals, $awayTeam, $awayGoals, $winnerID, 0)");

if ($cQuery){
        header('Location: ../results.php');
} else {
                echo mysql_error();
}


?>
```

Any help with this matter will be much appreciated. The functions.php contains no errors as this is all to do with database entry and not the authentication.

Comment: does using `===` help?

Comment: Cannot reproduce, http://codepad.org/5ISM5cqp also your want to exit/die after any redirect

Comment: comment out the `header()` line on your pesky IF, and instead echo "is true" then put an else and echo "is false", then after the closing `}` of the else put `exit();` (simple code for testing something specific). What gets echoed? I'm sure it will be "is true" and you'll find the IF is not actually "not firing" :)

Comment: You may have a point about the exit(); I totally forgot about that! Thank you very much I shall try that now!

Comment: @djjavo yeah because of no `exit()`, code is most likely getting executed after the expected redirect, making the if look like its not working.

Comment: @James It replies is true! So I need to put exit() after the headers. Do I also need to put exit() after each function?

Comment: just after any header redirects, if you have other code which can echo/DB query etc after the redirect, it will do that first. fyi, you can use `exit(header(location: blah));`. The test I put in my last comment saves me a lot of pain, as it narrows down problems. ie showed you "is true" which means your IF is working and you need to rethink where the issue lies ;)

Comment: Thanks everyone for all your help. Such a simple solution I feel really silly. Kudos to the community for being patient :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a `die();` after the `header("Location:...");`

Answer (score 0):

As your comparison code (the "if" part on line 12) that you pasted has to work, i have two advice:

1. Put a die(); or exit(); after the header() part.
2. Try looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10541439/header-location-relative-path-compatibility), as I am not sure if header() will work, while the location path you set is relative. Basic advice is to always use base paths for redirects, like "http://your.site.com/script.php").