# Redirect to the folder the file is located

Tags: php, forms, redirect, browser

I have a php form that i have on one domain.
If i copy all files to another domain.
How can i change my redirect so it goes to index.php in the same folder?
So if i copy all files to another folder or domain, it will work without any editing.

This how it looks today.

```
/* Redirect browser */
```

header("Location: http://my_domain.com/Folder/");
/* Make sure that code below does not get executed when we redirect. */

So if i copy all files to http://my_domain.com/app/

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for [\_\_DIR\_\_](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.magic.php) or one of the [\_SERVER](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) values, in PHP? Something that changes when you move the file around on your server.

Comment: Please share more details. Why do you need this after all? Why not configure your webserver itself properly? Also, please do not use irrelevant tags - otherwise explain how this is related to forms or browser

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Header Location relative path compatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10541439/header-location-relative-path-compatibility)

Answer (score 0):

One way to deal with this would be to use relative path but since you have hardcoded your domain, you could replace it with `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` or `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` ([$_SERVER](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)). You can then use something like this:

```
header("Location: http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/Folder/");
```